# JavaScript REST-API file upload security/ACL

Tags: security, parse-platform

I have a HTML5 static site and use Parse as the back end through REST API.
So my application id and REST API key are completely open to the public.

My classes have ACL so it should be relatively OK. But I also upload files to https://api.parse.com/1/files/ using JavaScript through REST-API .

How can I allow that only logged in users can upload files? Unlike normal classes on which I can set class wide ACL, anyone can upload files to my parsing application.

Answer (score 0):

First off I would ask why you are using the REST API instead of the native JavaScript API... the JavaScript API uses the REST API under the covers, it just adds a nicer layer of interaction to work with.

Anyway, that aside you can't stop people from uploading files unfortunately. You can stop them from assigning those files to records via ACLs though, and you can do a cleanup on files that are not linked to objects.